# Checking a for progression in a list of variables

Tags: php, math, comparison

Let's say I want to check for simple mathematical progression. I understand I can do it like this:

```
if ($a<$b and $b<$c and $c<$d and $d<$e and $e<$f) { echo OK; }
```

Is there a way to do it in a more convenient way? Like so

```
if ($a..$f isprog(<)) { echo OK; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don 't know if I get your problem right. But propably the solution for your progression could be the SplHeap object of the SPL delivered with php.

```
$stack = new SplMaxHeap();
$stack->insert(1);
$stack->insert(3);
$stack->insert(2);
$stack->insert(4);
$stack->insert(5);

foreach ($stack as $value) {
    echo $value . "\n";
}

// output will be: 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of values, iterate over them and maintaining a flag that checks if the current element value is greater than / less than that of the next value. Unlike some of the solutions in this thread, this doesn't loop through the whole array. It stops looping when it discovers the first value that's not a progression. This will be a lot more **faster** if the operation involves a lot of numbers.

```
function checkIfProg($arr, $compare) {
    $flag = true;
    for ($i = 0, $c = count($arr); $i < $c; $i++) {
        if ($compare == '<') {
            if (isset($arr[$i + 1]) && $arr[$i] > $arr[$i + 1]) {
                $flag = false;
                break;
            }
        } elseif ($compare == '>') {
            if (isset($arr[$i + 1]) && $arr[$i] < $arr[$i + 1]) {
                $flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $flag;
}
```

Usage:

```
$a = 2;
$b = 3;
$c = 4;
$d = 5;
$e = 9;
$f = 22;

$arr = array($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f);
var_dump(checkIfProg($arr, '<')); // => bool(true)
```

If you want the array to be created **dynamically**, you could use some variable variable magic to achieve this:

```
$arr = array();
foreach (range('a','f') as $v) {
    $arr[] = $$v;
}
```

This will create an array containing all the values of variables from `$a` ... `$f`.

Answer (score 0):

I havent heard of something like this, but how about using simple function:

```
function checkProgress($vars){ //to make it easie i assume that vars can be given in an array
  $result = true;
  for ($i=0; $i<= count($vars); $i++){
    if ($i>0 && $vars[$i] > $vars[$i-1]) continue;
    $result = false;
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: Hm. Returns true for both 1,3,4,7,9,18 and 1,3,4,7,5,9,18 while must return false on the second one.

Comment: Sorry i forgot `$` in for loop  `for ($i=0; $i<= count($vars); i++)` edited and fixed

Comment: Thanks, I used your example but can't upvote due to lack of rep.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it quick and dirty:

```
function ispositiveprogression($vars) {
 $num=count($vars)-1;
 while ($num) {
  $result = true;
  if ($vars[$num] > $vars[$num-1]) {
   $num--;
  }
  else { $result = false; break; }
 }
 return $result;
}
```

Comment: 1) make it a function, so it's reusable. 2) don't mix levels (boolean result VS result text).

Comment: This doesn't allow for checking for a reverse progression (`<`). And as @Karoly said , it's a good idea to wrap this into a function so it's reusable. I've added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22280698/1438393) showing how to do that.

Comment: Yes, I know it doesn't. I will come with a better answer, but that'll do for now. At least it works.